# Python Logging Start-up (verbose) to memory, then dumping subsets of that based on configuration settings: Any example?

Tags: python, logging, configuration

I'm writing a program with some fairly complicated configuration settings (with options from the environment, from the command line, and from a couple of possible configuration files).  I'd like to enable very verbose "debug" level logging to memory during all this configuration reading and initialization --- and then I'd like to selectively dump some, possibly all, of that into their final logging destinations based on some of those configuration settings, command line switches and environment values.

Does anyone here know of a good open source example I could look at where someone's already done this sort of thing?

It looks like the [Logging: MemoryHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#memoryhandler) should be able to do this ... initially with a `target=None` and then calling `.setTarget()` method after the configuration is parsed.  But the question is, can I set the MemoryHandler loglevel to DEBUG, then set a target with a different (usually less verbose) loglevel, and then simply `.flush()` the MemoryHandler into this other handler (effectively throwing away all of the overly verbose entries in the process)?

Answer (score 0):

That won't quite work, because `MemoryHandler`'s `flush()` method doesn't check levels before sending them to the target - all buffered records are sent. However, you could use a filter on the target handler, as in this example:

```
import logging, logging.handlers

class WarningFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.levelno >= logging.WARNING

logger = logging.getLogger('foo')
mh = logging.handlers.MemoryHandler(1000)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(mh)
logger.debug('bar')
logger.warning('baz')
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
sh.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
sh.addFilter(WarningFilter())
mh.setTarget(sh)
mh.flush()
```

When run, you should just see `baz` printed.

Comment: Actually that was what I was thinking ... is setting the different level (per my configuration) on the target handler before the .flush()